# How to get audio data in a specific format in real time from a Twilio MediaStreamTrack?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, twilio, mediastream, twilio-video, mediastreamsource

I am using Twilio Programmable video, and trying to pipe remote participant's audio in real time to Google Cloud Media Translation client.

There is a sample code on how to use Google Cloud Media Translation client via microphone on [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/media/docs/streaming#translating_speech_from_a_microphone).

What I am trying to accomplish is that instead of using a microphone and `node-record-lpcm16`, I want to pipe what I am getting from Twilio's `AudioTrack` to Google Cloud Media Translation client. According to
[this doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript-getting-started#video-api-overview),

> Tracks represent the individual audio, data, and video media streams that are shared within a Room.

Also, according to [this doc](https://sdk.twilio.com/js/video/releases/1.20.0/docs/AudioTrack.html), `AudioTrack` contains an audio `MediaStreamTrack`. I am guessing this can be used to extract the audio and pipe it to somewhere else.

What's the best way of tackling this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

With the `MediaStreamTrack` you can compose it back into a `MediaStream` object and then pass it to a [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder). When you start the `MediaRecorder` it will receive `dataavailable` events which will be a chunk of audio in the webm format. You can then pipe those chunks elsewhere to do the translation. I wrote a blog post on [recording using the `MediaRecorder`](https://www.twilio.com/blog/mediastream-recording-api), which should give you a better idea how the `MediaRecorder` works, but you will have to complete the work to stream the audio chunks to the server to be translated.